# Apple Developer Account Enrolment - Individual Account - Seller Name

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-id, apple-developer

I've recently developed an iOS app and am about to publish it, so I tried to sign up for an Apple Developer Account (I reside in Hong Kong). Then I realised that unless you own a limited company (or 'incorporated'), you'd have to sign up the 'Individual Account', which means that under the 'Seller Name' in the App Store, it will be your real personal name, instead of your company name that will be displayed. I do have a company but an unlimited one (Sole Proprietor) and I definitely prefer having the company name displayed under the 'Seller name' in the App Store.

Since the Developer Account's name is associated with the name in your Apple ID, I was thinking of renaming my name in my Apple ID to my company's name (my company has two separate words so they will fit into the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' field), but not sure whether it will have any implications (e.g. receiving revenue) going forward or if Apple will request personal identification at any given point.

Has anyone out there got any pointers? Would love to be more sure before paying for the $99 fee. I've been searching the internet for a good few days without much luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I would contact directly Apple support about this..

Answer (score 1):

For Change seller name as a company , you need D-U-N-S Number which is free, after this you can change you seller name by requesting directly to Apple Support, Apple will update your same account without any charges.